# use timeout and run ping in background and save the statistics to file

Tags: ping, timeout

I'm writing a script to automatically do the ping test. because I have hundreds  of endpoint to ping each other, and I don't want the script stop running because the ping stuck, so I use timeout, and run the ping in background. and I also want to save the ping statistics to file.
firstly I tried below commands:

```
timeout 20s ssh hostA "ping -c 30 -I 192.6.2.50 192.6.2.28 " | awk '{print "from 50 to 28 |",$0;}' &
```

and I got the result shows in screen which is what I expected:

```
from 50 to 28 | PING 192.6.2.28 (160.6.24.28) from 192.6.2.50 : 56(84) bytes of data.
from 50 to 28 | 64 bytes from 192.6.2.28: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.264 ms
from 50 to 28 | 64 bytes from 192.6.2.28: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.245 ms
from 50 to 28 | 64 bytes from 192.6.2.28: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.220 ms
from 50 to 28 | 64 bytes from 192.6.2.28: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.214 ms
from 50 to 28 | 64 bytes from 192.6.2.28: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.123 ms
....
Killed by signal 15.
```

but when I tried to save this output in file, it failed, below is the command I used:

```
timeout 20s ssh cic-1 "ping -c 30 -I 192.6.2.50 192.6.2.28 " | awk '{print "from 50 to 28",$0;}' | tee -i -a path/timeout_test.txt &
```

but I got nothing in timeout_test.txt

I also tried command below, I created the timeout_test.txt before the command run.

```
timeout 20s ssh cic-1 "ping -c 30 -I 192.6.2.50 192.6.2.28 " | awk '{print "from 50 to 28",$0;}' >> path/timeout_test.txt &
```

but still I got nothing.

Comment: hmmmmm.... I found that if I change the count of ping time to 3 (or any number that to finish the ping within 20s) the statistics can be written to file, but if the ping is ended by timeout, the result will not written to file.   So new question is, how could I write the output to file even the ping ended by timeout?

Comment: You can edit your posts, please do so.

Comment: Hundreds of endpoints `ping`-ing each other should be managed by dedicated software such as [monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/), not by ad-hoc scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I would first think about that you're running the ping Command on the SSH Server/Remote PC, so that the result there should be used by tee -a command on a file on that remote. By the way instead of dropping/piping everything in one shell line I would prefer to use intermediate files and then to work on the log results.